# Cannot update UITableView after view is loaded

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, refresh

I'm still a but noobish with obj-C , i'm creating an app with a tableview that need to be refreshed when i add items to the tableview. I googled it and found some answers saying i need to use `[self.tableView reloadData]` but it doesn't work for me.

here is my code for my tableView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
     return 1; }

- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     NSString *myTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Runs"];
     return myTitle;
      }

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     return [entries count];
     }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
 forIndexPath:indexPath];

     // Set up the cell...
     NSString *cellValue = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

     return cell; 
}
```

here is the code where i populate the table

```
- (void)populateTable{
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSString *username = appDelegate.username;
     entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
     [self openDB];
     NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Savings WHERE username = '%@'",username];
     sqlite3_stmt *statement;

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(runnerAppDB, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
     {
         while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
         {

             char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
             NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];

             //   username - distance - speed - date - comment
             NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ - %@", field1Str];
             [entries addObject:str];

         }
     } }
```

What i already tried to do is to call the populateTable function everytime i add something to the db , but still it doesn't refresh , can someone help me please ? been stuck with that problem for some time now.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't ever create a cell to begin with, check using debugger what it returns, I think it will be nil.

Comment: Michael, you should get a grip on iOS development first before you start writing code for you app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: It give an error on "self.myTableView" . i don't even have any autocompletion about my tableView after I type "self." Do you know why ?  i don't know what it's wrong because i can have the values in the tableView, i just can't update new ones . thanks

Comment: IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;  declare into .h file
Now set outlet it into .xib file
Now [myTableView reloadData]; worked

Comment: my UITableView stays empty :/ , maybe I should mention i'm not using Xib files but i'm using storyboard ?

Comment: @Michael : Then assign tableView in storyboard

Comment: Both my delegate and my dataSource are linked to my SecondViewController (view where the tableView is) and the tableView is linked to the outlet.  The UiTableView still doesn't update / reload his data :/

Comment: Declare one myTableView then link this table view with your storyboard then it will worked....

Comment: in your populateTable method add last [myTableView reloadData];

Comment: Your UITableViewCell's aren't being initialised, they will always be empty, no matter how many reloads!  Look at zing's answer, you need to create an instance of a cell if there is no cell to dequeue.

Comment: @Chirag : i don't know... it's not working. i linked to outlet to the viewTable, i pretty much put [myTableView reloadData]; in every function to check  and it's still not working.  Is there maybe a place where i have to change the tableView i'm using,  since i added the outlet now ?

Comment: @Michael : I have one sample code if you need it then give me your email address.

Comment: @Michael : I send you sample code check it then me what happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your table after all the data is in your array from which you are feeling your table .
and in tableview's cellforrowatindexpath method you need to reuse the cell . please update your cellforrow method.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

   NSString *cellValue = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your entries array gets all the data from your db ??
Or get some another way to get the data , and make sure that your array is updated with the data using NSLog . 
after getting all the data , add [urTableView reloadData];
This is the standard way of implementation.

Comment: I can see values in my tableView , so i guess i can acces the data from the DB.. my problem is , after i add something new to the database, i can't refresh my viewTable

Comment: After adding some values in your db , are you again calling your populateTable method , to update your array ??
and also check that your db gets updated or not ??

In your populate.. method , you are allocating your array every time . Instead of this, "entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];"
add this in your viewDidLoad ()

Answer (score 0):

Once data source of the table getting changed, then only u need to reload the table. Just check whether your reloading the table view once the data source is affected. Like this.

```
- (void)populateTable{
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSString *username = appDelegate.username;
     entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
     [self openDB];
     NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Savings WHERE username = '%@'",username];
     sqlite3_stmt *statement;

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(runnerAppDB, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
     {
         while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
         {

             char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
             NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];

             //   username - distance - speed - date - comment
             NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ - %@", field1Str];
             [entries addObject:str];

         }
     }
   [self.tableView reloadData]
 }
```

Comment: I have that,  the problem is that it doesn't refresh. my application has 3 tabs , the 2nd was is the one with the tableView. It only save the state of the first time i click on the tab. so if i add something and goes on the 2nd tab , the value will be added, but if i add again it'll stay on the 'old' version.